# "Macintosh HD - Data" and "Macintosh HD - Data - Data" but no "Macintosh HD"

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

I recently upgraded from High Sierra (10.13) to Big Sur (11.4). My Mac is functioning fine as far as I can tell; however, I noticed that I no longer have a "Macintosh HD" disk. Instead I have "Macintosh HD - Data" and "Macintosh HD - Data - Data". Here's what it looks like in Disk Utility:

[image]

Is this a problem? And if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: idk how it got that way, but there's nothing wrong with it other than the naming convention got broken somehow. The greyed out disk is your boot volume, which would nominally be called 'Macintosh HD' The data drive is usually  just called 'Data' in there, though it shows on the Desktop as 'Macintosh HD'. I don't have a Mac with default naming that has been upgraded from High Sierra, only ones that came already with Big Sur, so I can't really make an answer out of this.

Comment: It's odd but you should be able to right click on the drive (partition) you want to rename and just rename it from there. Apple wouldn't let you change the name if it were a problem to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the Disk Utility application. An example image is given below.

   [image]
2. Right click on `com.appleos.update-F...`, and select `Rename`. An example image is given below.

   [image]
3. Look for the highlighted text `Macintosh HD - Data`. An example image is given below. Change the text to `Macintosh HD`, then press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
4. Quit and open the Disk Utility to verify the change. An example image is given below.

   [image]

---

I should point out the you can also just rename the writable volume mounted at `/System/Volumes/Data`. For example, I could rename the `Macintosh HD - Data` volume shown in Step 4 to `Bugs Bunny`, as shown below.

[image]

I should also point out that the default name for the writable volume mounted at `/System/Volumes/Data` is just `Data`, if you have a M1 Mac.